# Show a value after making a selection in a drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a markup like this

```
<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">United States</option>
<option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

Now my requirement is when I select anything from drop-down the its respective value should be as a value.
Can anyone suggest something how to achieve this. I was thinking to do this onChange but problem is when second time I click on drop-down the value will re replaced.

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, especially "its respective value should be as a value"

Comment: See a a normal behavior o/p is <br/>
India <br/>
United States <br/>
United Kingdom<br/>

Now as a normal user when i click on india the selected value should be 1 in drop down.

Comment: I think I understand. When the menu pops up, you want to see all the country names, but when the user makes a selection and it closes, you want to see the number. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. `mouseup` doesn't work, but `mousedown` does! And my solution also doesn't need you to write the country names twice.

```
$('.country').change(function() {
    var selected = $(':selected', this);
    var index = this.selectedIndex;
    if (index) {
        selected.data('savedtext', selected.text()).text(index);
    }
});
$('.country').mousedown(function() {
    $(':selected', this).text($(':selected', this).data('savedtext'));
});
```

​[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/aVBKq/3/)

EDIT:

Here's another version that shows the option value, not the index:

```
$('.country').change(function() {
    var selected = $(':selected', this);
    var value = selected.val();
    if (value) {
        selected.data('savedtext', selected.text()).text(value);
    }
});
$('.country').mousedown(function() {
    $(':selected', this).text($(':selected', this).data('savedtext'));
});​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/aVBKq/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<select name="country" class="country">
   <option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
   <option value="1" data-text='india'>India</option>
   <option value="2" data-text='United States'>United States</option>
   <option value="3" data-text='United Kingdom'>United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

```
$('.country').change(function(){
    $('option', this).text(function(){
       return this.dataset.text
    })
    $(':selected', this).text(this.selectedIndex)
})
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/aVBKq/
    ​

Comment: Yup, thanks for helping, Its something like this but again when I click on drop-down the text should be there no values as text. In current senario If i select United States it will show 2 which is correct but again when i click on drop-down the United States get replaced by 2 which should not be.

Comment: @saorabh That needs a hacky solution.

Comment: I tried modifying your fiddle to use `mouseup` instead of `change`, but that event doesn't seem to fire on a select menu. This may need to be done using a pop-up menu plugin rather than the standard `<select>`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, he should use other solution, even click is not fired.

Comment: Thanks @undefined for your help. Will try to achieve this without using select or may be with custom select box plugin.

Answer (score 0):

When you use 
`$("select[name='country']").val();` by default the proper value will display. For --Select-- use 0 as value.

Comment: That doesn't _display_ anything, it just returns the option value. He wants to change how the menu itself appears when it's closed.

Comment: I can not understand. Can you post what is your output should be...